# List data urls in a webpage

Tags: html, r, url, download

In order to download automatically all the files presented in a webpage (data urls differ from the webpage url), I have to extract those data urls fro the html code. 
Here is how I do it:

```
library(XML)
url <- "http://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/dataset/registre-parcellaire-graphique-2012-contours-des-ilots-culturaux-et-leur-groupe-de-cultures-majorita"
doc <- htmlParse(url)
```

In `doc`, I what to retrieve the data urls in this div:

```
<div class="list-group-item" data-url="https://www.data.gouv.fr/storage/f/2014-02-13T13-50-47/RPG_2012_087.zip" data-format="shp" rel="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="top" title="Registre Parcellaire Graphique 2012 - Département de la Haute-Vienne (87) [shp]" data-content="Registre Parcellaire Graphique 2012 - Département de la Haute-Vienne (87)">
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Richard has mentioned, the help page offers many examples as demos. If we know the pattern of links present, example in our case `<div class="list-group-item"`, we can try the following

```
library(XML)
url <- "http://www.data.gouv.fr/fr/dataset/registre-parcellaire-graphique-2012-contours-des-ilots-culturaux-et-leur-groupe-de-cultures-majorita"

#Save and read html file,replace the filname here 
doc <- htmlTreeParse('doc_fr.htm',useInternalNodes = TRUE)

#The pattern required for subsetting links
doc_nodes=xpathSApply(doc,"//div[@class='list-group-item']",xmlAttrs)
row.names(doc_nodes)
#[1] "class"          "data-url"       "data-format"    "rel"            "data-trigger"   "data-placement"
#[7] "title"          "data-content"

#The links are present in second row from above
doc_links=doc_nodes[2,]

head(doc_links,5)
#[1] "https://www.data.gouv.fr/storage/f/2014-02-12T09-44-05/Description_RPG_2012_SHP.rtfd.zip"                 
#[2] "https://www.data.gouv.fr/storage/f/2014-02-12T09-50-50/RPG_2012_%20Codes_groupes_cultures_et_couleurs.csv"
#[3] "https://www.data.gouv.fr/storage/f/2014-02-12T09-57-24/RPG_2012_001.zip"                                  
#[4] "https://www.data.gouv.fr/storage/f/2014-02-12T13-26-51/RPG_2012_002.zip"                                  
#[5] "https://www.data.gouv.fr/storage/f/2014-02-12T13-28-03/RPG_2012_02A.zip"

#Get file names from links
unique(do.call(rbind,lapply(strsplit(doc_links,split="/"),function(x) length(x))))
#     [,1]
#[1,]    7

#replace space with underscore in output file name
raw_fnames=do.call(rbind,lapply(strsplit(doc_links,split="/"),function(x) x[7] ))
raw_fnames=gsub('%20',' ',raw_fnames)
new_fnames=gsub(' ','_',raw_fnames)

#Download all files
lapply(1:length(new_fnames),function(x)  download.file(doc_links[x],destfile=new_fnames[x]) )
#trying URL 'https://www.data.gouv.fr/storage/f/2014-02-12T09-44-05/Description_RPG_2012_SHP.rtfd.zip'
#Content type 'application/zip' length 128101 bytes (125 Kb)
#opened URL
#downloaded 125 Kb
```

Comment: Would you happen to know why sometimes I get `Error: failed to load HTML resource.` and sometimes I don't?  I feel it may be a memory issue, and I maybe need to `free()` the html docs, but I didn't save any.

Comment: thanks great answer! I was stuck at the xpath step, though I had something close!

Comment: Richard,I was stumped by the same issue and very reluctantly had to work with manually saved html file.I think its a combination of memory and connection timeout. The other error I faced was this   `getURL(url)
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : couldn't connect to host`

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try.  It returns all the links on the URL page.  This answer is taken almost word-for-word from the `htmlParse` help file.  The `getLinks` function is really useful.

```
> library(XML)
> getLinks <- function() { 
       links = character() 
       list(a = function(node, ...) { 
                   links <<- c(links, xmlGetAttr(node, "href"))
                   node 
                }, 
            links = function()links)
     }
> h1 <- getLinks()
> htmlTreeParse(url, handlers = h1)
> h1$links()
```

And to get back all the URLs that contain the word "data", you can do

```
h1$links()[grepl("data", h1$links())]
```